# Ubuntu shutting down on battery power

Tags: kernel, power-management, shutdown, battery, crash

I am newbie to Ubuntu and trying to figure out why my laptop is shutting down suddenly when an intensive task is running. When the laptop is plugged to AC it doesn't happen, for the very same intensive task (training neural nets).

At the beginning overheating was the most suspicious reason for that to happen but found a tutorial on how to run a script with a combination of sensors command (lm-sensors) and grep, let it running and saw temperatures were not going over 75 degrees celsius... but the machine shutdown aswell. Checked again the logs after rebooting and temps didn't rise above 75celsius.

And I insist, when running on AC power it doesn't shutdown.

So I tried to check kern.log and system.log but found no apparent reason or at least can't interpret any reason critical enough for the machine to shutdown. Find attached some .log entries for both files just before the crash.

It is not such a hassle then I can work plugged to the AC but sometimes I need to do heavy data proceassing in spreadsheets and when copying >100k rows it crashes too. So definetely when an intensive task is running, and the machine is running on battery power, it will shutdown sooner or later, despite temps not rising above 75degrees.

```
Machine Specs:
Xiaomi Mi Notebook Pro 15"
IntelCore i7 8550u
16GBRAM 256GB SSD
GraphicCard NVIDIA
```

(there's debate on the internet wether NVIDIA and its proprietary driver is involved in these power problems, but setting it back to the default driver doesn't help)

If anyone can shed some light on what might be happenign would be awesome. many thanks for your help.

Carlos.

=====================================================

Crash Info: happened on 29thMarch at 19:17:13 
(exact time extracted from my temp logging script, it was the last second the log monitorized the cpu cores temperatures)

(KERN.LOG)

```
Mar 29 18:44:29 CarlosUbuntu kernel: [   43.851930] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Mar 29 18:44:29 CarlosUbuntu kernel: [   43.851943] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Mar 29 18:44:29 CarlosUbuntu kernel: [   43.851955] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
Mar 29 18:44:30 CarlosUbuntu kernel: [   44.912172] rfkill: input handler disabled
Mar 29 19:17:56 CarlosUbuntu kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x96, date = 2018-05-15
Mar 29 19:17:56 CarlosUbuntu kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.18.0-16-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-006) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)) #17~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 12 13:35:51 UTC 2019 (Ubuntu 4.18.0-16.17~18.04.1-generic 4.18.20)
Mar 29 19:17:56 CarlosUbuntu kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-16-generic root=UUID=552ebc31-e839-401f-8da5-8878c3df88b7 ro quiet splash, nouveau.modeset=0
Mar 29 19:17:56 CarlosUbuntu kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Mar 29 19:17:56 CarlosUbuntu kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Mar 29 19:17:56 CarlosUbuntu kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
Mar 29 19:17:56 CarlosUbuntu kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
```

(No records close to the crash time)

=======================================================

(SYSLOG)

```
Mar 29 19:08:07 CarlosUbuntu gnome-software[2185]: no app for changed ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
Mar 29 19:16:49 CarlosUbuntu gnome-software[2185]: no app for changed ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
Mar 29 19:16:49 CarlosUbuntu gnome-software[2185]: no app for changed ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
Mar 29 19:16:49 CarlosUbuntu gnome-shell[1534]: [AppIndicatorSupport-DEBUG] Registering StatusNotifierItem :1.73/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/software_update_available
Mar 29 19:16:49 CarlosUbuntu gvfsd-metadata[1860]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Mar 29 19:16:49 CarlosUbuntu gvfsd-metadata[1860]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Mar 29 19:16:49 CarlosUbuntu gnome-shell[1534]: can't init metadata tree /home/carlos/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root: open: Permission denied
Mar 29 19:17:01 CarlosUbuntu CRON[2935]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Mar 29 19:17:02 CarlosUbuntu dbus-daemon[1382]: [session uid=1000 pid=1382] Activating service name='org.gnome.gedit' requested by ':1.61' (uid=1000 pid=1781 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
Mar 29 19:17:02 CarlosUbuntu dbus-daemon[1382]: [session uid=1000 pid=1382] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.gedit'
Mar 29 19:17:56 CarlosUbuntu systemd-modules-load[295]: Inserted module 'lp'
Mar 29 19:17:56 CarlosUbuntu systemd-modules-load[295]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Mar 29 19:17:56 CarlosUbuntu systemd-modules-load[295]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Mar 29 19:17:56 CarlosUbuntu systemd-modules-load[295]: Inserted module 'coretemp'
```

(records before and after the crash at 19:17:13)

Comment: We may or may not learn something if you were to add the big spew of stuff from turbostat (linux-tools-common package) when it starts up for both battery and AC. Also turbostat is a better tool for monitoring processor package and core temperatures. example command: `sudo turbostat --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgTmp,PkgWatt,IRQ --interval 15`

Comment: The shutting down is probably the battery. How old is the computer and battery? The temps are another thing. 75celsius is high. If the computer is older, it may have a lot of dust in it. Open the computer and use some compressed air to blow it out. Worst case, the thermal paste on the CPU needs refreshing. You could also install `thermald` to see if that can keep things cooler. The CPU intensive crashing could be something else... edit your question and show me `free -h`. Report back.

Comment: it is definetely not a battery issue. Yesterday I was performing long taks that weren't as demanding as training neural nets, where temperatures stayed well below 70C and running on battery power. After 3 or 4h had to plug the charger then the battery was fully empty. The point is that I reach seldomly temperatures of 80C running on charger and computer stays fine. The same thing running on battery and it shuttsdown at roughly 75C. Can I tweak this somehow? I believe I should be able to do that throgh the bios... but not a related option there... thanks again guys